# What is (in simple understanding) narrow contract and wide contract in terms of c++ interface(s)?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface

While walking through some `c++11` concepts, I came across the terms `narrow contract` and `wide contract`.

But I failed to figure out a simple function example(s) which is/are written for these contracts.

**Can I see a simple function example that distinguishes between these two contracts?**

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0147r0.html)?

Comment: Got some idea ...Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wide contract functions have well-defined behavior for all possible inputs, while narrow contracts mean that the functions can only be called when certain preconditions are met.

Some caveats:

- "Input" might also include global state or the object for which a member function is called.
- All possible inputs don't include invalid objects (e.g., the result of an invalid cast).
- Well-defined behavior might mean throwing an exception.

For example, `std::vector<int>`-s `.size()` member function has a wide contract because it can be called on any instance of a vector (as in `std::vector<int> v; /* anything can happen with v here... */; auto s = v.size();` is always valid). The `operator[](size_t index)` (as in `int x = v[10]`) has a narrow contract, because it can only be called with a parameter that is less than `.size()`, otherwise it is undefined. The `.at(size_t i)` member function (as in `int y = v.at(10)`) however has a wide contract, because it is specified to throw an exception when the index is out of range.

Preconditions are not always easy to verify: For pointers such as `int* p`, the `*` operator has a narrow contract, because you can only dereference a pointer when it points to a valid object, but there is no general way to verify a pointer before dereferencing it.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying the idea of "all possible inputs". The type system can (broadly speaking) _prove_ certain constraints about the input to a function (`char f(int n)` is proven, at compile-time, to never be passed anything but an `int`). There may be constraints on that input that are impractical (or genuinely literally impossible) to express as a proof in the type system. So if `f`, for whatever reason, can't handle `int`s that are a multiple of 5, then it has a "narrow contract". `25` is a "valid" input to `f` in the sense that it typechecks, but it isn't expected.

Comment: When people (generally in functional programming circles) talk about "making incorrect programs inexpressible", they're gesturing toward the idea of making all functions have wide contracts. If the programmer wants there to be some constraint on the input or output of a function, they want to find a way of expressing that constraint in the type system. If you can do that, you can prove that a program that compiles will handle any input that it might receive at runtime (see also: Curry-Howard correspondance).

Comment: Thanks @Zaaier  added a clarifying bullet point to the caveats.