# Can std::string::compare(const char*) throw an exception?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is overload (4) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)

In the "Exceptions" section, overloads 2,3,5,6 (which have pos1 and/or pos2 parameters) are named as throwing `std::out_of_range`.

Overload (4) does not have "pos" parameters, but it's not marked `noexcept`.

Is it up to the implementation whether it throws or not?

In GCC 7's libstdc++, it calls `char_traits<char>::length` and `char_traits<char>::compare`. These don't seem to be able to throw, but aren't marked `noexcept`.

Comment: Honestly not sure why this question is getting so many upvotes.. `Clang` has it as: `int compare(const value_type* __s) const _NOEXCEPT;` So does GCC: `int
      compare(const _CharT* __s) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT;` https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L2988

Comment: Looks like it's up to implementation, but logically it seems like it should be `noexcept`.

Comment: I guess we need a language lawyer to get the real answer...but I would assume, that the standard does not require `std::string` to store the string as a `CharT *`, in order to allow small string optimization. However, this also means that we might have to do some conversion for the actual `compare` to happen. This conversion might have to allocate memory, which could be exhausted and therefore possibly throw. Thus, the standard cannot enforce a `noexcept` from implementations, although they still might be `noexcept` in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for destructors, swap functions, move constructors and move assignment operators, the standard marks a function `noexcept` only if it has a [*wide contract*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292673/what-is-in-simple-understanding-narrow-contract-and-wide-contract-in-terms-of), i.e., it has no preconditions. This overload requires the argument to be a null-terminated string, so the standard does not mark it as `noexcept`.

The rational is specified in [N3248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf):

> ## Functions marked `noexcept` are difficult to test
>
> When a function is marked with `noexcept` it becomes impossible to flag test failures,
>   notably in test drivers, by throwing an exception. A common example would be code
>   that validates preconditions on entry to a function:
>
> ```
> T& std::vector<T>::front() noexcept {
>  assert(!this->empty());
>  return *this->data();
> }
> ```
>
> When validating such defensive checks from a test driver, a reasonable approach is to
>   register an assert-handler that throws a well-defined precondition-violated exception,
>   which the test driver catches to ensure that the appropriate `assert`s are indeed in
>   place.
>
> ...
>
> Now we might argue that calling the function out-of-contract, when the `vector` is
>   empty, is undefined behavior so we should not expect any guarantees. The problem is that undefined behavior is being specified by the library; to the compiler, this code is
>   perfectly well defined and, if `assert` throws an exception, the program must terminate
>   in a well-specified manner, thwarting the test driver.
>
> Note that the issue here is not that we are using assertions to find bugs in our own
>   library implementations, but rather in user code that incorrectly calls into our library.
>   If we remove the ability to test these defensive assertions, we may get them wrong,
>   and thus put our users at risk for committing far more serious errors than propagating
>   an unexpected exception.

---

By the way, due to [[res.on.exception.handling]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.exception.handling#5):

> An implementation may strengthen the exception specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing exception specification.

... `libstdc++` and `libc++` are free to mark this overload `noexcept`.