# noexcept constructor of std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, noexcept, user-defined-literals, string-view

According to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view), std::string_view has a constructor that takes a `const char *` and a `std::size_t`, that is not declared `noexcept`:

```
constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s, size_type count);
```

On the other hand, [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) states also that the user defined literal `operator""sv`, that in all the implementations I've seen is a simple wrapper to that constructor, is declared `noexcept`:

```
constexpr std::string_view operator "" sv(const char* str, std::size_t len) noexcept;
```

Do you know the reason of this difference? When is that the constuctor can throw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the constructor

```
constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s, size_type count);
```

you can pass anything as the string:

```
char c{'X'};
std::string_view sv{&c, 100}; // oops
```

Therefore, this function does not have a [wide contract](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51292673/9716597) (i.e., accepts all inputs), and is not marked `noexcept` per [N3279 Conservative use of `noexcept` in the Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf) — marking it `noexcept` would prevent libraries from including tests to help users discover bugs in their code (in debug mode, of course).  (See [Can std::string::compare(const char*) throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974315/9716597) for more information.)

---

On the other hand, the UDL operator

```
constexpr std::string_view operator "" sv(const char* str, std::size_t len) noexcept;
```

is usually called by the language when translating a literal:

```
using std::string_literals;
auto sv = "foo"sv;
```

There is no possibility of invalid pointer values passed in, so the operator is `noexcept`.  Of course, you can directly invoke the operator with an invalid value, but that's not the kind of problem that the standard library is supposed to handle.

Comment: @bolov Marking it `noexcept` would prevent libraries from having debug-mode tests.  That's the original rationale for [N3279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf).  You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974315/9716597 for more information.

Comment: You are right. Good inclusion of these 2 resources.