# Is it possible to declare template parameters within the template arguments of another template parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++20

I am attempting to create a class template that takes an `std::array` as a template argument. Currently, the declaration is as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::array<std::size_t, N> A>
class Foo {
    ...
}
```

This is quite unfortunate, however, as I will typically be initializing `A` with an initializer list, which makes the need to specify `N` tedious and redundant:

```cpp
// Current
Foo<int, 3, {5, 3, 4}> bar;

// Preferred
Foo<int, {5, 3, 4}> baz;
```

I have tried to use something similar to template template parameters to no avail:

```cpp
template<typename T, template<std::size_t N> std::array<std::size_t, N> A>
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or otherwise 'hide' `N` by placing it after `A` in the parameter list?

Comment: Regarding "*I will typically be initializing `arr` with an initializer list*", what is `arr`? Also, please show how you'll be creating an instance of Foo.

Comment: @cigien Edited, thank you

Comment: Why not just add `using A = std::array<std::size_t, N>;` to your template class?

Comment: @paddy how would that help, exactly? I don't believe that will let you specify the array as a template parameter, will it?

Comment: But `Foo<int, 3, {5, 3, 4}> bar;` doesn't work either.

Comment: If you're not obligated to use an array as an argument: `template<typename T, size_t... ARR_ELEMENTS>`. Then you could use `static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(ARR_ELEMENTS)> A = {ARR_ELEMENTS...};` to create the array in the class.

Answer (score 5):

There is the option of adding a wrapper, so the following code would work:

```
Foo2<as_std_array<5, 3, 4>> baz2;
```

With *as_std_array* being defined as:

```
template<auto item, auto... items>
struct as_std_array {
    using TYPE = std::common_type_t<decltype(item), decltype(items)...>;
    constexpr static std::size_t SIZE = sizeof...(items)+1;
    constexpr static auto ARRAY = std::array<TYPE, SIZE>{item, items...};
};
```

And *Foo*, *Foo2* as:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, std::array<T, N> A>
struct Foo {
    constexpr static auto ARRAY = A;
};

template<typename T>
class Foo2: public Foo<T::SIZE, typename T::TYPE, T::ARRAY>{};
```

Then the following works:

```
Foo2<as_std_array<5, 3, 4>> baz2;    
static_assert(baz2.ARRAY == std::array{5, 3, 4});
```

[Link to code](https://godbolt.org/z/4dh4a5rbd)

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use c++20 `auto` template arguments:

```
template<typename T, auto A>
```

Live demo using Boost to demangle the type:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/c55sTW5xa)**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, auto A>
struct Foo {
    void bar() const {
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(decltype(A)).name()) << "\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo<int, std::array{3,4,7}> f;
    Foo<int, std::array{'a', 'b'}> g;

    f.bar();
    g.bar();
}
```

Prints

```
std::array<int, 3ul>
std::array<char, 2ul>
```

### Variadic Packs

Otherwise I suggest just passing the array elements as a pack:

```
template<typename T, auto... A>
```

See it [Live Online](https://godbolt.org/z/7P6fhzaxr) (C++17)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, auto...>
struct Foo {
    void bar() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo<int, 3,4,7> f;
    Foo<int, 'a', 'b'> g;

    f.bar();
    g.bar();
}
```

Prints

```
void Foo<T, <anonymous> >::bar() const [with T = int; auto ...<anonymous> = {3, 4, 7}]
void Foo<T, <anonymous> >::bar() const [with T = int; auto ...<anonymous> = {'a', 'b'}]
```

Comment: For the variadic-pack example, it might make more sense to explicitly use the `std::size_t...` pack since that was the value type of the `std::array` in the question. Otherwise `Foo` now has to also handle making sure that all arguments are convertible to the correct/desired type

Comment: @Human-Compiler The thing is, there was an example using `size_t` alright, but didn't say that type wasn't hardcoded. But yeah, if you can, [narrow your contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292673/what-is-in-simple-understanding-narrow-contract-and-wide-contract-in-terms-of)!

Comment: `auto` template argument is a C++17 feature.