# noexcept, third party and STL calls

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I'm trying to understand when I should use `noexcept` and when I should not.

In my library, I have many methods. Some are using methods from third party, some are using the STL. Some use throw, some don't.

I can put `noexcept` statements on all my methods, the compiler just do not complain at all. But I do.

I can check my own throws to know if I should put a `noexcept` on a method, but am I supposed to check every signature of the STL methods and third party methods to know if I should put a `noexcept` ?

I could do that but that seems inefficient, am I missing something here ?

example code where I should NOT use `noexcept` if my understanding is correct:

```
foo::foo() noexcept
{
  this->BarPtr = std::make_unique<Bar>();
}
```

Comment: Only add noexcept if you only call other noexcept functions or if you can be sure you catch everything (preferably not using catch(...)). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique can throw exception std::bad_alloc so foo::foo() cannot be noexcept. (Or if you leave it noexcept then the program will exit immediately if std::make_unique does throw). So yes signature checking will be necessary.

Comment: If you have a bad_alloc exception there's little point to catch it. This is true for the vast majority of exceptions.

Comment: Put `noexcept` on any custom move constructors / assignment operators, assuming they're written that way (and they should be).  `std::vector` ❤️'s that.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis True, but if you do not catch in a "noexcept" function the program will terminate, not do stack unwinding to go to the next exception handler. Actuall adding noexcept may worsen performance due to that extra check.

Comment: @PepijnKramer the program should not rely to a stack of exception handlers to handle errors. If you get an exception, most of the cases the app must be terminated and recompiled. If you have an exception that you can handle it, then it shouldn't be an exception in the first place.

Comment: You could use conditional noexcept, but I'm not sure, if there's much benefit in doing this or if this just leads to a maintainence nightmare with little to no benefit: `foo::foo() noexcept(noexcept(BarPtr = std::make_unique<Bar>())) { ... }` Note that the `noexcept` operator may not yield the appropriate results. `std::strlen(str)` should pretty much be `noexcept` for any non-null zero terminated C string, but it's not marked as `noexcept`.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Oh no I totally disagree (or I misunderstand you), but using exceptions to handle errors can be very powerful.  I use exceptions (and RAII) all the time to seperate abnormal program flow from normal flow. It makes code (at least the happy flow) much more readable. Your comments make more sense when viewed from a firmware point of viewswhere exceptions might be too costly for now though (but even that's being worked on :  [Zero-overhead deterministic exceptions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0709r4.pdf)

Comment: You don't have to chase down anything. If you aren't sure about exceptions being thrown, then your method is "potentially throwing". That's the term used by the standard for operations that *are not* `noexcept`. So don't mark your method, it's only honest (lack of) advertisement.

Comment: Thanks Pepjin, Monica and Paul. Feel free to answer the question so I can accept an answer.

Comment: I think @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Is the most simple explanation out here. So...

Comment: @PepijnKramer - Alright

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis there are practical reasons to catch `bad_alloc` (example: photo editor shouldn't terminate and lose unsaved work if it fails to allocate buffer for image resize or a print preview page). If you only throw exceptions to terminate, be honest and call them "asserts".

Comment: @cubbi for that you only need a top level handler to do generic cleanup like saving unsaved work. Btw for a photoeditor if it fails to allocate buffer for an image resize then it's buggy and the error should be fixed instead of be caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to chase down anything. If you aren't sure about exceptions being thrown, then your method is "potentially throwing". That's the term used by the standard for operations that *are not* `noexcept`. So don't mark your method if you aren't sure, it's only honest (lack of) advertisement.

That's not to say you should never be bothered about it. For example, move operations that are `noexcept` can enable/optimise the use of certain standard containers. So if you are writing a custom one, it's worthwhile to try and determine if you can mark things `noexcept`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> - As an anecdote, I dealt once with a class that held a member of a type that was written for C++03. The semantics of the type did permit throwing (it had a [narrow contract](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51292673/817643)) for invalid inputs or copies thereof, but we only *generated* valid ones. So I marked the move operations `noexcept` to facilitate use of a standard container that was appropriate.

Comment: One extra note : A throw in a noexcept function will result in program termination directly so better be safe then sorry. Live demo here : https://godbolt.org/z/vM85drccv

Comment: Thanks, I know understand how to use noexcept.